# Joomla virtuemart 2.0.18a related products

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using joomla Virtuemart version 2.0.18a. I have to display related products on product detail page. I didn't find related products option in **Virtuemart 2.0.18a**.

In **Virtuemart 2.0.22a** has same option in product > custom fields >  "Related Products" & "Related Category" options. Same functionality i need in Virtuemart 2.0.18a.

Is there any way to show related products in Virtuemart 2.0.18a?

Comment: What is stopping you from upgrading to 2.0.22a which has this feature? You should always keep your extensions up to date for new features and bug/security fixes.

Comment: Yes, I know that. This is one option we have. But If we have any other idea for same functionality is working in lower version. This is common function in shopping cart, that features has been included. B'z I have review the database. Database has table "_product_relations" mean this features is alredy added in same features. But how this feature is working that i am not knowing. I have done my best to search same thing.